# Create user without populating session token

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

My question is very simple. Is it possible to create a user object without Parse-Server automatically creating a session token?

I have tried this code.

```
const myNewObject = new Parse.Object('_User');
myNewObject.set('username', 'myCustomKey1Value');
myNewObject.set('password', 'myCustomKey2Value');
let user = await myNewObject.save(null,{ useMasterKey: true });
```

Not working.

Any solution?

Comment: I believe that a session token is always created for a new user.

Comment: Yes, I believe so too. The only way would be to manually search for the session object and delete it.